# fgetcsv(), delimiter is not being recognised

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I am trying to use fgetcsv() to grab data from a CSV file to a HTML table.

I am able to put the data into the HTML table, but I would like the table to have two columns, and separated by a "|" character.

I have the line :

```
fgetcsv($file, 999, "|");
```

However, the delimiter seems to be ignored and everything is input into one column?

this is my code:

```
<table>
<?php
    $file = fopen("WSfile.csv", "r");
    
    
while (! feof($file)){
    $lines = fgetcsv($file, 999, "|");
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach((array) $lines as $line){
            echo "<td>" . $line . "</td>";
        }
    echo"</tr>";
}
fclose($file);

?>
</table>
```

Comment: The delimiter in [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is for reading from the CSV file, not for it's output.

Comment: Can we see a sample of the source data please? if the columns in the CSV file are not separated by a `|` then fgetcsv will read everything into one column per line. As mentioned above, this delimiter controls how the data is read from the file. It has nothing to do with how you output it later in HTML. Currently you're looping through all the lines and then trying to print each the whole of each line inside a single HTML table cell. You're also not creating a new HTML table row for each line of the CSV (which I assume you might want).